# Using the Central Limit Theorem to approximate a binomial probability

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Here's my problem:

> In Ohio, 55% of the population support the republican candidate in an
>   upcoming election. 200 people are polled at random. If we suppose that
>   each person’s vote (for or against) is a Bernoulli random variable
>   with probability p, and votes are independent,
>
> (a) Show that the number of people polled that support the democratic
>   candidate X has distribution Bin(200, .45) and calculate the mean and
>   variance.
>
> (b) Calculate directly the probability that more than half of the
>   polled people will vote for the democratic candidate. Tell me the
>   equation that you used to solve this.
>
> (c) Use the CLT to approximate the Binomial probability and calculate
>   the approximate probability that half of the polled people will vote
>   for the democratic candidate

And here's what I got so far:

**Part a:** 
Let us suppose if X number of people are supporting the democratic candidate, then there can be $\binom {200} {X}$ possible ways to select the people
$\binom {200} {X} (0.45)^X (0.55)^{1-X}$
Therefore the given distribution is binomial distribution with n=200, p =0.55 and 1-p = 0.45

According to the theorem, the mean of the probability distribution is given as
$E(X) = n*p = 200 * 0.45 = 90$

The variance of probability distribution is given as $E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = np(1-p)$

For this problem,

$200*(0.45)*(1-0.45) = 49.5$

**Part b:**
More than half of the people voting for the democratic candidate would be equal to $\sum\limits_{i=101}^{i=200} \binom {200} {i} (0.45)^i (0.55)^{200-i}$

**Part c** I'm at a total loss.

I'm very new to these sorts of problems and suspect I might be way off the mark on every part. Any guidance would be appreciated. (Apologies if this is way too long a problem, I can split it up.)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{200}X_i$, where $X_i=\{\text{No.i person votes for the democratic candidate}\}$, so that $$X_i\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
p & 1-p\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

You have already calculated $E(X)$ and $D(X)$. So according to CLT, $X\sim?$

Answer (score 0):

$c)$ Let $X\sim Bin(200,.45)$ that counts the number of votes for the democratic candidate so $X=\sum_{i=1}^{200}\xi_i$ where $\xi_i\sim Bernoulli(.45)$ and $\xi_i$ are i.i.d. so by central limit theorem we have that:
$$X\sim^{\star}N(np,np(1-p))$$
$$X\sim^{\star}N(90,49.5)$$
So:
 $$P[X> 100]=1-P[X\leq100]\approx $$ $$1-P\left[\dfrac{X-90}{\sqrt{49.5}}\leq \dfrac{100-90}{\sqrt{49.5}}\approx1.4213\right]$$
$$=1-.07885=.92115$$